# PdfLatex to Pdf

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to compile from PdfLatex to Pdf but i keep getting this error. 
What should I do?

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \section
```

Below is a part of my code

```
% file name : switch-models.tex 
%  input to HW-2-main.tex 
% 
% for compsci190-2013F
\section {FHN switch models} 



\begin{itemize}  
\item Review of the three switch models in lecture notes 
\item Suggestion : think of {\em infinitesimal changes} in time
  and the corresponding potential. 
\end{itemize} 

\vspace{1 cm} 


\subsection{Model (1)} 

Consider the basic model for a single switch.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need a `\documentclass` declaration at the start of your file, say `\documentclass{article}` and then `\begin{document}` before the text. You probably have them in `HW-2-main.tex`, which is the file which you should run LaTeX on.

Comment: Sorry, but please read _any_ manual on LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

you have mutiple files, but main file must begin with `\documentclass{style}` e.g. `\documentclass{article}` , a MWE is presented below

```
\documentclass{article} % %

\begin{document}  % %
\section {FHN switch models} 



\begin{itemize}  
\item Review of the three switch models in lecture notes 
\item Suggestion : think of {\em infinitesimal changes} in time
  and the corresponding potential. 
\end{itemize} 

\vspace{1 cm} 


\subsection{Model (1)} 

Consider the basic model for a single switch. 
\end{document} % %
```